# What is this plant growing beside my house?

Tags: identification

[image] [image]

Please excuse the somewhat stark photography. I'm currently in tech week for the show I'm in, so I don't get home until well after dark. This plant is growing in the patch of land where [the grass is still failing to grow](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/19874/getting-grass-to-grow-on-top-of-hill-shady-area-with-possible-concrete) even after adding more soil and reseeding with a shade/drought-tolerant species.

As can be seen in the pictures, it's got a 7-pointed lobed leaf. My first thought is that it looks a little like a tree, maybe a poplar or maple, but I'm not botanist. I'm happy enough that anything is growing there, but I'm curious. If it helps, all of this sprung up within a few weeks.

Here is a close-up of one of the leaves:

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's a match. The leaves are different, the shape is different... :)

Comment: The first link is to an immature plant. Mature, they tend to look more like this: http://www.diamon-naturals.us/lambs%20quarter.jpg Also Lambsquarter. In low-light environments the plant will often get longer between the nodes as it tries to get taller and reach for more light.

Comment: It's possible, but the leaves still don't look right. The Lambsquarter has very serrated edges and non-distinct lobes. This one seems to have a distinct set of lobes and points with smoother edges in between. I've added a close-up of a leaf from a higher-resolution original image.

Comment: This is exactly what lambs quarters look like when mature in my garden

Comment: Incidentally, before I could get to it, the plant got cropped to the ground, no doubt by the local deer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fairly certain this is Common Lambsquarter. Chenopodium album. [Common Lambsquarter](http://www.ipm.ucdavis.edu/PMG/WEEDS/lambsquarters.html) Perhaps the margins are a bit different because it is in some shade?

Comment: That is possible. :) I'm not certain how I would eventually find out...

Comment: I'd pull it up and go on!  Before it goes to seed...?  It is definitely a weed.  Possibly edible if you don't over-do.  This is in your yard?  Pull it out...!?